# Pass values dynamicaly to the name={}; and get there particular values

Tags: javascript

```
var Clientnametotal=["Raj","Raj","Kumar"]


 Clientnametotal.forEach(function (x) {
                        namecount[x] = (namecount[x] || 0) + 1;
}
```

if am writing below line of code i will get the output as 2

```
alert(JSON.stringify(namecount.Raj));
```

but i need to pass the names dynamically like this

```
alert(JSON.stringify(namecount.Clientnametotal[0]));
```

but output comes like this `[object Object]`. Raj its not giving output

How i can get the values?

Comment: You need to provide a sample output of what you want it to look like after the function runs, and an example value of the namecount object, then we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are just looking for the bracket notation:

```
alert( JSON.stringify( namecount[ Clientnametotal[0] ] ) );
```

Comment: Thank you.. i am  trying the same but i not kept brackets now i got Thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

When you have to deal with dynamic keys, use the bracket syntax rather than the dot (.) syntax.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(namecount[Clientnametotal[0]]));
```

Please also note that it's useless to `stringify` a number since it will already be converted to a string by `alert`. If you just wanted to convert it to a string, you could also do `namecount[Clientnametotal[0]].toString()` or `namecount[Clientnametotal[0]] + ''`.

Bascially this gives the same result:

```
alert(namecount[Clientnametotal[0]]);
```